# Delete a pivot table row without knowing one of the foreign keys

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I currently have a pivot table (pending invites) joining a groups table and contacts table. There are 4 columns:

id | group_id | contact_id | email

email field is simply the email id of the contact involved. I have a situation where I need to remove a pending invite when I know the group_id and the corresponding email, but not the contact id. The standard detach function:

```
$groups->contacts()->detach($contact_id);
```

requires the contact id to be supplied. Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: I think you should keep the `email` field in the `Contact` model, and leave if of the pivot table. Then find a `Contact` with the given e-mail address and detach it from the `Group`, like so: `$group->contats()->detach($contact->id);`

Comment: will that work even if there are multiple rows in the Contact model with the same email (thus giving me multiple contact_ids)? I ask because I also have a one to many relationship between a User model and the Contact model. I will add that information to the question if you feel it is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just manually remove selected rows from the pivot table:

```
\DB::table('contacts_groups')
  ->whereGroupId($groupId)
  ->whereEmail($email)
  ->delete();
```

Comment: I was looking for an eloquent based command using the pivot. But if nothing like that is possible, I'll accept your answer

Comment: Eloquent relation classes (like BelongsToMany) allow only to detach records based on related model's id. It's not possible to detach based on other attributes from pivot table in a simple way. You could of course fetch all related records with given email and then iterate through them and detach them by their IDs but it wouldn't be efficient.